# JavaScript function for retrieving multiple querystring values

Tags: javascript, html, querystringparameter

This function works only for a parameter.

```
function getQueryStringValue(key) {
   debugger;
   return unescape(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + escape(key).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));
};
```

Please I need a JavaScript function that can retrieve more than one querystring parameter, I need to pass the name of the parameter as key to the function. Thank you

The function in the link Alex shared is as below

```
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) {
            url = window.location.href;
        }
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    };
```

With my url as this:

```
       var url= 'search-results.html?param1=unth?param2=lagos';
```

And I pass this to the function :

```
     var param1 = getParameterByName('param1');
     var param2 = getParameterByName('param2');
```

It return param1 as : luth?param2=lagos
instead of luth.

This is the same issue with the function I shared.
My question is a JavaScript Function that retrieves multiple querystring parameter but the function works only for one parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you Alex. I will test the function in the link and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL should be: 
`var url= 'search-results.html?param1=unth&param2=lagos';`

In this case function will work.

`var param1 = getParameterByName('param1'); //return unth`

`var param2 = getParameterByName('param2'); //return lagos`

Comment: Thank you a lot SouXin. You are right. It is working now after the amendment.